# Image Uploading Php

Tags: php, html

I am able upload image in localhost.But for uploading on my server, image is not uploading. 
I get this message

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(ajax/28.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\raynfotechnologies.com\httpdocs\raynfosoftware\addemployees.php on line 205
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpB296.tmp' to 'ajax/28.jpg' in D:\inetpub\vhosts\raynfotechnologies.com\httpdocs\raynfosoftware\addemployees.php on line 205
```

Host is a windows server.

php code:

```
<?php 
  $pid=mysql_insert_id();
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"ajax/$pid.jpg"); 
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="jesform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <div class="input-icon input-icon-sm"> 
        <input type="file" class="form-control input-sm"  name="file"> 
      </div>
```

Comment: do you have the file permissions set correctly on your server?

Comment: yes,Folder Public permissions,group permisions,owner permissions  read,write,execute is on..

Answer (score 0):

you are having a permission problem

check this url
http://www.howyoudo.info/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-server-upload-file-inherit-permissions-error/

or this other
http://chris.wastedhalo.com/2011/01/wordpress-upload-permissions-on-iis-7-fix/

best
Emiliano